# How do you open an Amiga A590 Power supply?

Tags: amiga, power

I have an Amiga 590 hard drive, but the power supply appears to be dead on it so I want to take a look inside. I have removed three screws from the underside but it still won't open, acting like there's a screw in the top righthand corner (as you look at it from underneath).

Am I missing something obvious? It looks like this underneath

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last (and only) Amiga 590 PSU I have ever seen actually **had** four screws,  all hidden under plastic cones that need to be removed first. (All four holes visible in the picture hold a screw).

EDIT After you supplied a picture: Apparently, one of the cone plugs is still in there in the top right. The easiest way to remove the plug is to drive a self-tapping screw in there and pull it out. Below the plug, you should find the last screw.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Mine's different. I've added a picture now.

Comment: Cone plug it was. It looked like part of the moulding. I didn't realise that it could be removed.